# Finding the mean of a distribution

Tags: python-3.x, mean

My code generates a number of distributions (I only plotted one below to make it more legible). Y axis - here represents a probability density function and the X axis - is a simple array of values.

In more detail.

```
Y = [0.02046505 0.10756612 0.24319883 0.30336375 0.22071875 0.0890625 0.015625  0  0  0]
```

And X is generated using `np.arange(0,10,1) = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]`

I want to find the mean of this distribution (i.e where the curve peaks on the X-axis, not the Y value mean. I know how to use numpy packages np.mean to find the mean of Y but its not what I need.

By eye, the mean here is about x=3 but I would like to generate this with a code to make it more accurate.

[image: My graph is attached here]

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the mean (actually, the expected value of a random variable `x`, but since you have the PDF, you could use the expected value) is `sum(p(x[j]) * x[j])`, where `p(x[j])` is the value of the PDF at `x[j]`. You can implement this as code like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Y = np.array(eval(",".join("[0.02046505 0.10756612 0.24319883 0.30336375 0.22071875 0.0890625 0.015625  0  0  0]".split())))
>>> Y
array([0.02046505, 0.10756612, 0.24319883, 0.30336375, 0.22071875,
       0.0890625 , 0.015625  , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ])
>>> X = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> Y.sum()
1.0
>>> (X * Y).sum()
2.92599253
```

So the (approximate) answer is `2.92599253`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was partially aware of that formula but wasn't sure how to implement it.